# Rex ex to find a number of items

Tags: javascript, regex

Reginald X. Pression I need your help! 
I've got a regular expression that will look for comma separated integers

```
/\(\d{0,2},?\d{0,2},?\d{0,2},?\d{0,2},?\)/g
```

which will match up to four (two digit) numbers

- (3) // no comma needed if it's only one number
- (3,2)
- (2,3,4)
- (99,99,99)
- (1,2,3,4)

However, it's limited to four sets of numbers. I can repeat the pattern in the reg ex to match more, but is there a way I can look between 1 and 10 comma separated numbers without filling up the reg ex with lots of iterations of "\d{0,2}," ?

Needs to match

- (1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10)
- (1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,99)
- (99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\(\d{1,2}(?:,\d{1,2}){0,3}\)
```

Try this.THis will match upto `4` `2` digit numbers separatedby `,`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/19

```
\(\d{1,2}(?:,\d{1,2}){0,9}\)
```

You can use this for upto 10 iterations.